# PHP DateTime modify() doesnt work with time

Tags: php, date, datetime

When I use the DateTime->modify() it doesn't keep my time. Does it not support time? How can I get my time back?

My time I'm using: 2020-10-31T18:30

The time I'm getting: 2020-10-31 00:00

What I want: 2020-10-31 18:30

```
$user_inputed_date = date('Y-m-d g:ia');
$users_inputed_time = strtotime($user_inputed_date);

$date_ymd = date('Y-m-d', $users_inputed_time);
$date_time = date('H:i', $users_inputed_time);
$date = $date_ymd.'T'.$date_time; // 2020-10-31T18:30

// we have this 24 hour format time 2020-10-31T18:30
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
// get next wednesday
$dateTime->modify('wednesday');
// this returns 2020-10-31 00:00. why did it lose the time?
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: I'd guess because if you say "go to wednesday" it takes it literally and moves to the _start_ of wednesday. So it's not so much that it "lost" the time, but simply that you told it to go to a precise point in time, which happens to be midnight Wednesday

Comment: Right. If you use `+1 day` it means to add a day and keep the same time.

Comment: You might be better to work out how many days away Wednesday is, and then modify the date by that many days (i.e. `+3 days` or whatever) - that will preserve the time as it advances the date _by_ a specific quantity of time, rather than advancing it _to_ a specific point in time.

Comment: Or extract the time from `$date` and then concatenate the day name. `Wednesday 18:30`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next Wednesday is the same as the next Wednesday 00:00. If you want to keep the time you have to chain the next Wednesday with the time as Barmar said in the comment:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2020-10-31 18:30:00');

$dateTime->modify('next wednesday'.$dateTime->format(' H:i:s'));

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//2020-11-04 18:30:00
```

Due to the processing sequence in PHP, it is possible to do this with one line of code.